# Introspection Endpoint validate both token issued by same client and other clients

Tags: oauth-2.0, oauth-2.1

I am using OAuth 2.1 compliant authorization service.

1. There are two oauth2 clients "client-1", "client-2"
2. Create access access token using "client-1"
3. Introspect generated token using "client-1", "client-2"

Return success response from "client-1" and error response (Invalid client) from "client-1".

with this case, If two applications have same permissions each application accept other application issued tokens. Resource server need to validate introspection response client id and application client id before authorization.

As [1] and [2] this is correct behavior.

[1]. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/issues/1501

[2]. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7662#section-2.3

As I understood this case has security issue. Any reason to allow this.

Answer (score 0):

Introspection should be thought of as a process for getting token data for an opaque access token. Introspection often runs in an API gateway then forwards token data to resource servers (APIs). Expired tokens fail introspection.

Introspection is not a substitute for authorization. Each API should authorize using the access token data. First check for the required issuer, audience, scopes and claims. Then apply business rules.

In the authorization server, each client should be configured with least privilege access tokens. Clients can be given different (or the same) audience, scopes, claims. This enables you to control which clients can call which APIs. Eg ensure that a client with `marketing` scope cannot call a `finance` API.

Ideally the introspection response should be a JWT access token. Some authorization servers support this. The JWT can then be forwarded to APIs, which keeps the access token verifiable as it flows.

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed answer. I need further clarification. First check for the required issuer, audience, scopes and claims means we need to validate issuer and audience in resource server. We should check client id same to audience. Am I correct?

Comment: APIs don't check client IDs, since it is easier to receive access tokens from multiple clients that way. Instead, scopes represent client capabilities, so each API checks for  its own required scope(s).

Comment: That's true. What happen in this case. There are two independent applications and they use one authentication server with two different clients. There are two APIs with work with same name scopes in both applications. That case both applications work with any client access token. Is this haven't any issue ?

Comment: Login flows should ensure that each app can only get its own access token. It is often a valid setup for APIs to share some scopes. The usual thing to ensure is that an app's access token cannot be used at APIs for a completely different business area.